# Sumar atributos de objetos en Java

Tags: java

¿Cómo hago para hacer la suma de los valores de los productos? El valor esperado en este caso seria $18,300.
De ante mano muchas gracias.

Por ejemplo:

```
        Ventas producto1 = new Ventas("Leche", 14000);
        Ventas producto2 = new Ventas("calaos", 800);
        Ventas producto3 = new Ventas("Salchichas", 2800);
        Ventas producto4 = new Ventas("Tomate", 500);
        Ventas producto5 = new Ventas("pan", 200);
```

Comment: Podrías explicar a qué te refieres con "sumar varios objetos", podrías dar un ejemplo del resultado que esperas vs lo que tienes

Comment: @EduenSarceño, el valor esperado en el caso propuesto es de 18.300. Sin embargo hay que tener en cuenta que se pueden enviar N cantidad de productos.

Comment: @Jorge Leonardo Cardenas Monten, podrías poner tu clase Ventas como la tienes?. Supondo que tendrás tus métodos setter y getter. Una manera de calcular lo que quieres sería utilizando la Stream API.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que aplicar programacion orientada a objetos es decir tu clase "Ventas" deberia tener algo como esto:

```
public class Ventas{
private String producto;
private double precio;

/*
Constructor, al construir se solicita pasar por parametro el nombre del producto y su costo algo como 
lo que ya tienes "Ventas producto5 = new Ventas("pan",200);"*/

public Ventas(String producto, double precio){
 // se hace las asignaciones a las variables locales de lo que recibio
this.producto=producto;
this.precio=precio;
}

/*Y ahora para poder sumar los montos de cada producto se declara un metodo "Get"*/
public double getPrecio(){
return this.precio;
}

}
```

Y ahora si en la clase en la que intentas realizar la sumas hacer lo siguiente

```
public class SumarMontos{
    Ventas producto1 = new Ventas("Leche",14000);
    Ventas producto2 = new Ventas("calaos",800);
    Ventas producto3 = new Ventas("Salchichas",2800);
    Ventas producto4 = new Ventas("Tomate",500);
    Ventas producto5 = new Ventas("pan",200);
    double total=0;

public void sumarMontos(){
total = total + producto1.getPrecio();
total = total + producto2.getPrecio();
total = total + producto3.getPrecio();
total = total + producto4.getPrecio();
total = total + producto5.getPrecio();
}

}
```

y obtendras el total que deseas en la variable "total"
nota: no recomiendo copiar el codigo que he puesto aqui ya que no he usado algo que verifique la sintaxis.

---

¿ como volver la sumatoria de manera automatica y añadir nuevos productos?
Usa tu imaginacion para ello tenemos ArraysList y arreglos
podrias hacer lo siguiente

```
public class SumarMontos{
    ArrayList <Ventas> productos = new ArrayList();
    double total=0;
// Cada vez que quieras agregar un nuevo producto ejecutas este metodo
public void agregarNuevoProducto(){
   productos.add(new Ventas("el nombre del nuevo producto",2000));//<- y su precio
}
//Cada vez que quieras saber el total ejecutas este metodo
public void sumarMontos(){
    total = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<productos.size();i++){
      total = total + productos.get(i).getPrecio();
    }
}

}
```

No es un regaño pero esto es basico.

Answer (score -1):

```
System.out.println(producto1.valor + producto2.valor + producto3.valor 
+ producto4.valor + producto5.valor);
```

Comment: Solo colocar código de considera de baja calidad, dale editar y añade una explicación

Comment: Ok. No lo sabía.

Comment: Podes apretar el boton [edit] y arreglar la respuesta. Agrega porque esto solucionaria el problema. Explica la solucion